# Security Considerations when using Ansible

Tags: ansible

Ansible is SSH based so I am wondering if that raises any security Considerations/concerns of something have SSH access to the servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit off-topic but I'll take a stab.

Make sure you patch your ssh servers with the latest release regularly.  Also, don't use passwords to login. Use rsa/dsa private/public key pairs to login and run your playbooks. 
If you want to take it up a notch use 4096 bit, 8192 bit or even greater bit key pairs.

Every time you ssh login to your servers using key pairs ssh creates a unique one-time fingerprint for authentication. So if your spoofer gets it he/she can't use it again to login. In contrast, when you use a common password you always run the risk of getting spoofed (Man in the middle ssh service for example).  Using an IP address to connect to your server instead of an FQDN reduces the risk of spoofing (It's easier to pretend to be a DNS name than to pretend to be an IP address in the Internet)

You can also play some other tricks with your firewall, for example you could only allow ssh locally and run your playbooks locally on your server (May be set it up as a cron job) You could get updates/new playbooks from a cloud repository like github.

Like somebody else mentioned you can also allow ssh access to the IP address where you are running the playbooks from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are that paranoid you could always lock it down to come from a designated source ip - true Jane hacker could forge her ip but as ssh requires sending and receiving to create the connection she would have to do a lot of spoofing to use and exploit it...